# Erro no retrofit2 converter-gson:2.1.0

Tags: android, gson

Estou tendo um erro muito persistente no Retrofit2 esta com erro na linha

```
GsonConverterFactory.create()
```

Já tentei diversas coisas e nao consigo fazer rodar.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(UdacityService.BASE_URL)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

Meu gradle esta da seguinte forma:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

Álguem sabe como solucionar, por favor?

Comment: Que erro você está recebendo? (Edite sua pergunta)

Comment: Em vez de `addCallAdapterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` não será `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`?

Comment: Poste como resposta, não como comentário, a correta informação da resolução do teu problema e marque como correta. Assim ajuda outros que tiverem a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Era exatamente isso!! muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de

```
addCallAdapterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
```

é

```
addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
```